# PHP ERRO - Consultas preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom dia a todos, estou iniciando em PHP, acompanho um curso através do youtube. Estou estudando consultas preparadas. Tenho um formulário que faz uma consulta no BD, porém, ao inserir os dados, surge a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in

Abaixo o código:

```
<?php 

        $c_art = $_GET["c_art"];

        $secc = $_GET["secc"];

        $n_art = $_GET["n_art"];

        $pre = $_GET["pre"];

        $fec = $_GET["fec"];

        $imp = $_GET["imp"];

        $p_orig = $_GET["p_ori"];

        include ("dados_banco.php");

        $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

            echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";

            exit();

        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db_nombre) or die("No se encunetra la  BBDD");

        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

        $sql="INSERT INTO productos (CODIGOARTÍCULO, SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAISDEORIGEN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $resultado=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

        $ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssssss", $c_art, $secc, $n_art, $pre, $fec, $imp, $p_ori);

        $ok=mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

        if($ok==false){

            echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";

        }else{

            //$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $codigo, $seccion, $precio, $pais);

            echo "Agregado nuevo registro";

            /*while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)){

                echo $codigo . " " . $seccion . " " . $precio . " " . $pais . "<br>";

            }*/

            mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
        }


     ?>
```

Comment: `$resultado` é falso logo falha a consulta.

Comment: Faça `$resultado=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));` e coloque a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Laerte, fiz o teste q pediu e notei que o problema estava em algumas colunas do banco.. mt obrigado, funcionou! abraços.

Comment: Acredito que na coluna com acento agudo no nome, correto?

Comment: Não, Jhonatan.. o curso q estou acompanhando é em espanhol (tambem achei esquisito ele usar acentos), e to seguindo conforme é apresentado.. foi em outro campo o problema.. obgd pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, o problema esta nessa linha:

```
$ok=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssssss", $c_art, $secc, $n_art, $pre, $fec, $imp, $p_ori);
```

de acordo com sua query, são esperados 7 valores e você esta passando 9:

```
INSERT INTO productos (CODIGOARTÍCULO, SECCION, NOMBREARTICULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAISDEORIGEN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```